# "Elements" of algebraic structures

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra

Let $T$ denote an algebraic theory, and $e$ denote the $T$-algebra freely generated by a singleton set, and write $U$ for the forgetful functor. Now suppose we're given a $T$-algebra $A.$ We might say that an *element* of $A$ (as opposed to an element of $U(A)$) is just a morphism $f : e \rightarrow A$. Let us write $f \in A$ to mean that $f$ is an element of $A$, and $x \in U(A)$ to mean that $x$ is an element of $U(A)$.

Now lets fix some notation; $e$ is generated by a singleton set, so lets go ahead and call the sole element of that set $k$.

Then every $x \in U(A)$ determines some $f \in A$, namely it is the unique $f : e \rightarrow A$ satisfying $f(k)=x$. Similarly, every $f \in A$ determines some $x \in U(A)$, namely $f(k)$. These processes should be invertible.

This suggests the following. Let $\mathbf{T}$ denote the category of $T$-algebras. It should (essentially) be possible to recover the canonical forgetful functor $\mathbf{T} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ just by knowing which object of $\mathbf{T}$ is the free object on one generator.

> **Question**. Where can I get more information?

Comment: It seems to me like you've already answered your question. The free object on one generator is the object representing the forgetful functor to $\text{Set}$. (Indeed this is how one defines the free object on one generator from the perspective of category theory.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, ah yes but I just wanted to learn a bit more. What can we do with these elements? How do they help us?

Comment: What elements? Help you do what? For starters, two useful terms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representable_functor, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors. Bonus: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory).

Comment: Oh, those elements. Well, as you already know, they are the same as elements of the underlying set. So you can do with them exactly what you can do with elements of the underlying set. These are occasionally useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The forgetful functor is $\hom(e,-)$. As Qiaochu said, this is essentially the definition of the free algebra on one generator.